# Trouble Importing/Exporting in MX format

Tags: export, import

I want to save some definitions to an `.mx` file in order to be able to load them quickly. However, I run into a strange problem.

If I do,

```
Export["file1.txt", Definition[test1]]
```

I get a file containing the definitions I want (this is human readable, so I can check the file contains what I want) and I can then load it with `Get["file1"]` after which the definitions have been loaded.

However, when I do the same with the MX format:

```
Export["file2.mx", Definition[test1], "MX"]
```

and then `Get["file2.mx"]` it returns `Null` and does not load the definitions (of course here I cannot check whether the mx file really contains the correct definitions so I don't know whether the issue is in saving or loading the file).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your first example I get *"Export::infer: Cannot infer format of file file1."* are you sure you are not giving a file extension?

Comment: @rhermans, sorry I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The issue

From the documentation of `Definition`:

> `Definition[symbol]` **prints** as all values and attributes defined for *symbol*.

(emphasis mine)

The key here is the word "prints": `Definition[symbol]` only looks like the definitions of `symbol`, it's not actually replaced by them:

```
f[x_]:=x^2
Definition@f
FullForm@Definition@f
(* f[x_]:=x^2 *)
(* Definition[f] *)
```

Exporting in a human readable format causes the `StandardForm` of the expression to be exported (please correct me if it's another form), which is why it works. Exporting to `"MX"` exports the `FullForm`, which does not do what you want:

```
file=FileNameJoin@{$TemporaryDirectory,"test.mx"};
Export[file,Definition@f];
FullForm@Import[file]
(* Definition[f] *)
```

## How to do what you want

Basically, see [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html).

Comment: Thanks. I should have known. I have been burned by this before, but I forgot.